# how to use ef code first with sql server ce in asp.net mvc 4 visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a simple EF code first sample using SQL server compact edition 4.0.
Technologies used include: Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

So i created a simple poco class:

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a simple context class:

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class CustomerEntity : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to create a controller class with the template: MVC Controller with read/write actions and views using entity framework.

- Model class -> Customer
- Data context class -> CustomerEntity

I got the following error:

> Unable to retreive metadata for ... Using the same dbcompiledmodel to
>   create contexts against different types of database servers is not
>   supported. ...

I should say this exact same code worked without problem using LocalDB.

The only difference that I thought was needed, was the addition of the following to the web.config file.

```
<add name="CustomerEntity"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|CustomerEntity.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Am I missing something else?

I know I can't be the only one having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in dublicate DB in EF cache and DB in your App_Data. The easiest way to resolve this problem is to comment your default constructor **CustomerEntity**, to create controller from template and then uncomment it.